# Basic Scope Connection

Tags: angularjs, scope

I just started AngularJS a few days ago and I've read that scopes are immediately updated whenever the value of their linked element changes. I have this HTML code with my controller:

```
<div ng-controller="lyricsMod">
<textarea ng-model="valueB"></textarea>
{{valueA}}
```

And my AngularJS controller:

```
myMod.controller('lyricsMod', function($scope) { 
$scope.valueA = $scope.valueB;
});
```

However, this outputs nothing. But, changing the HTML code to:

```
<div ng-controller="lyricsMod">
<textarea ng-model="valueA"></textarea>
{{valueA}}
```

Produces the wanted result. Pretty sure it has nothing to do with the AngularJS and that its just linking two things together in HTML. I don't understand, if the scope is immediately updated, why is this not working?

Comment: You need to bind the changes in model to another $scope variable. you can use ng-change for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try it:**

u need to make use of $watch if you want change scope variable on change of other scope variable

```
myMod.controller('lyricsMod', function ($scope) {
                $scope.$watch('valueB',function(){
                    $scope.valueA=$scope.valueB;
                });
                $scope.valueA=$scope.valueB;
              });
```

Comment: But what happened to AngularJS two-way data binding? Doesn't the scope automatically update when the view is changed and the view changes once the scope changes? As such, shouldn't scope.valueB automatically change since it's equal to scope.valueA?
Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: Angularjs does two-way data-binding but you are like initializing $scope.valueA with value of $scope.valueB when controller is initialized. You need an event(like ng-change) if you want to change value of other scope variable or listen to the change of scope using $watch. if you declare 'ng-model=valueA' and change its value , the change will be reflected directly on your view without any listener or event ... dats two-way data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

> scopes are immediately updated whenever the value of their linked
>   element changes

Yes but only scope variables bound using `ng-model`.  In your fist example `ValueB` is bound using `ng-model` not `valueA`.If you want to change value of another scope variable when another changes(and its bound using ng-model). Use `ng-change` directive.

```
<div ng-controller="lyricsMod">
        <textarea ng-model="valueB" ng-change="changeA()"></textarea>
        {{valueA}}

$scope.changeA = function () {
       $scope.valueA = $scope.valueB;
    }
```